# Pause video on flowplayer cuepoints

Tags: jquery, video, video-processing, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer for the first time, i simply want to pause my video when video reaches a cuepoint. I've checked and tried everything but noting is useful for me so far. Can someone tell me a simple and effective solution?
I am using data-cuepoints and here is an example how i am using cuepoints.

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-cuepoints="[1.5, 2, 3, -1]">

</div>
```

All i want is a simple jQuery code which can pause my video on these points.
Thank you in advance... a little help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got the answer as well.

```
<script>    
    flowplayer(function (api, root) {
      api.bind("cuepoint", function () {
        api.pause();
      });
    });
</script>
```

This should be written before $(document).ready.